# admob ads waste space

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

It's not a good idea to leave 50dp space at the bottom or top or somewhere else for ad that only show up when user have internet access..

my app UI doesn't look nice when there's a blank left there.. how to actually do like only if the ad appear, and then able push other elements?

I tried apply padding to the ad, it doesn't work that way.. I have few buttons to click at the bottom, so you know it will be weird why a lots of blank space if ad is there..

help, help, my last concern, finishing my app~

Answer (score 0):

Specify the height of your ad to be `WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `50dp`. Until an ad is returned, the `AdView` will take up no space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do not specify the static height of the adView Layout, put it as **WRAP_CONTECT**.

Also do one thing, As you have said If there is no internet connection then the empty space looks like not good. So in your java code. check for the internet connectivity and if it is available then dont do anything and if it is available then then you statically put another layout at that position for nice appearance even if the internet is not available.

Hope you got my point.

comment me if any query.

Keep coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you device is not connected to internet. 
You should check if if have internet connection. And you should decide if you will let the user use your app knowing that you will no be receving any revenue from that user.